# Website works on any browser, but not on ie 6 and 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

http://antonioorv.altervista.org/italiaincontra/ this is the website I'm doing.. It works perfectly on Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Safari..and if works KIND OF good even on ie 8.

If i run it on ie7 that's what i get http://imageshack.us/f/267/istantanea2002201317153.png/ ......... as you can see half of the page is going to the left and half of the menu is vertical.

I don't really know what to do! is there something wrong with the doctype? or the meta tags? to make it work on ie 8 i added

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
```

is there something i should have done before the body tag that i didn't do?

Comment: Welcome to the box model.

Comment: IE 6 and 7 are bad browsers. They display things wrong because they're terrible software. It's nothing you did wrong, it's the browsers being awful. If you really want to make it look good on them, you need to add conditional stylesheets that display just for them.

Comment: Drop support for ie 7 and 6, it is not worth your time, or anyone's time here to try and help solve issues with those browsers. 6 is not even supported by Microsoft anymore and it's well past time they dropped support for 7 as well.

Comment: As a developer, I really recommend ignoring ie7 and ie6.  Very small and shrinking userbase, and the time that you will spend trying to get these old, dead, bad browsers to work is more than most of the other browsers combined.

Comment: @Tchalvak Dropping IE7 support completely is not quite realistic yet for a very large part of the world, myself included. Trust me, I'd love to - but can't because our clients and customers use it.

Comment: Not too bad, but I'd start your debugging here: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fantonioorv.altervista.org%2Fitaliaincontra%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201201-201301  IE7 share this month is 0.73%.  I'm aware that dropping IE7 support isn't necessarily ideal for a site that has tens of thousands of hits a month, or analytics says has a large percentage of ie7 users, but for a developer just starting to deal with web development's many issues, it's probably a good route to go.  Learning about IE8's problems, which will follow us for the next 5 years at least, is probably a better investment of time than ie7.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to summarize all of the comments for you and anyone else that has an issue with these browsers.

- [IE 6 is a dead browser](http://blogs.windows.com/ie/b/ie/archive/2012/01/03/the-us-says-goodbye-to-ie6.aspx), support has been dropped by Microsoft, you don't ever have to even think about supporting this nightmare again.
- IE7 is dying, and the quicker you and anyone else stop supporting it the quicker it will die. It is not worth your effort to try and support IE7. ***UNLESS*** a tool like Google analytics says otherwise.
- As a general rule, I recommend Google analytics to any web-developer that is creating a public facing site/application. It will tell you were your traffic is coming from and what % of each browser/os visits are bouncing off your site.

I manage at the moment 10 different sites. And I can tell you that my support for browsers is actually not universal across all those sites. On one of them less then 1% of traffic comes from IE 8 but 40% of traffic is coming from Safari. I can tell you that Safari gets far more support on that site then IE 8 does.

For more on this you can check out these resources:

- [Should I support IE7.](http://www.rickwhittington.com/blog/should-my-website-support-internet-explorer-7/)
- [Old browsers are holding back the web.](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/09/old-browsers-are-holding-back-the-web/)
- [Facebook Hates IE7, and dropped support.](http://thenextweb.com/facebook/2011/12/30/not-a-fan-of-timeline-on-facebook-use-ie7-facebook-stopped-supporting-it/)
- [IE7 isn't even on stats counter any more, and IE8 is at less then 12% world wide.](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201201-201301)

Comment: *"the quicker you and anyone else stop supporting IE7 the quicker it will die"* - Nonsense. Sorry to say but it doesn't work like that, as much as I wish it were true. *"Facebook Hates IE7, and dropped support."* - did you read the article? A little extra whitespace does not equal "dropped support" IMO. FB actually works pretty well on IE7.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Microsoft disagrees with you: quote from the first link: "In fact, we launched the IE6 Countdown site last March to help accelerate the process." They *wanted* support for IE6 dropped.

Comment: My comment (and yours which I quoted) was in regards to IE7, not IE6. IE6 is dead. I will say this though: We're getting there.

Comment: @WesleyMurch It's the same issue with IE7. Microsoft wanted support dropped, a year before they officially killed it. Which is when they launched that website - *'to help accerate the process'*. Also worldwide, IE7 support is at 4%.... so I am sorry your users are stuck in 2003 but most of the world does *NOT* need to support IE7.

Comment: In the business world, 4% is nothing to be scoffed at. How would you feel about a 4% pay cut? I'm sorry about it too, but that's the way it is. Not trying to argue really cos we're both on the same side, but I feel like you're brushing off the question asked. The OP may be required to support IE7 to the fullest.

Comment: @WesleyMurch discussions are not for comments. here is my last reply, in regards to your Facebook comment. Yes it works ok, but they officially don't work on it anymore. Any new features are not developed and not debugged in IE 7. Saying it works ok is not the same as supporting it. that is just a happy coincidence for Facebook.

Comment: "discussions are not for comments"? Fair enough about support VS "it happens to work". Looking forward to a brighter future free from IE7 (finally). Even 9 isn't so great, haven't used 10 yet.

Comment: @WesleyMurch haha, *the comments are not meant for discussions. English fail on my part.

Comment: IE7 is on stats counter, here: http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201201-201301  Not easy to mouseover, but this month or last it's 0.73%, and IE6 is 0.33%